# Crank angle during cycling conversion

Tags: conversion

I work in a laboratory, and we are performing experiments on a cycle ergometer, during which we would like to deliver magnetic stimulations during cycling exercise.

To do so, we need to know the angle of the crank, in order to standardise the angle at which we are stimulating.

We have sensors on the crank which give us the waves showed in the image. What I would like to do is convert this into the actual crank angle (i.e. between 0-360 degrees). This should look something like a triangle with a verticle drop when the angle passes from 360 to 0 degrees. Would anyone know if there is a calculation that I can perform in the software in order to convert to the actual angle? If we placed a goniometer around the crank, such that we could see the which value in the image is associated with a specific angle, perhaps this could take us towards a solution?

Many thanks in advance

[image: Current image]

Comment: Can you provide some more details about the signal? What kind of noise do you expect on it (e.g. white noise, 1/f noise, etc)? Does the amplitude vary with the crank speed?

Comment: What is V/f?  and range of this value? and output current waveform for magnetic stimulus. Sine to sawtooth is a simple algorithm but it varies with frequency which varies with voltage

Comment: There is very little variation in the amplitude, particularly as we will be keeping the crank speed consistant. There is some noise in the signal, although we can probably apply a filter or a smoothing function to remove any noise. The power output of cycling might vary between participants, but the velocity will always be kept the same (at around 40 rotations per minute on the cycle ergometer)

Comment: What is V/f? and range of this value? and output current waveform for magnetic stimulus

Comment: @Lightwelter My first *instinct* was a PLL of some sort (probably implemented numerically as a digital PLL) to track the sine, but it's probably overkill now given the above clarifications. Can you try filtering your raw data to see how clean of a sinusoid you're able to achieve?

Comment: What physical parameter is the sensor measuring ? angle ? strain ? force ? velocity ? What do the numbers on the Y axis signify ? raw ADC data ? degrees ? newtons ? m/s ? Give details about the sensor used as well as the mounting scheme and a link to its datasheet if any.

Comment: Consider borrowing from the automotive industry, they either add or remove a tooth.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a sine wave (roughly), you can compute the angle as follows:

- Normalize the waveform to +/- 1.0. Let's call this signal x(t).
- Compute arcsin(x(t)) of the normalized waveform

This would yield the angle. The problem you might run into however is that computing arcsin on every sample may add too much delay. Same thing with normalizing the waveform to unity.

Instead, you could normalize to a convenient signed binary range (-1023 ~ 1023, say) and use a lookup table. Note that you can exploit symmetry to make the lookup table smaller.

If your waveform isn't a perfect sine you could characterize it vs. a sine and make adjustments to your lookup table. That's something you couldn't do with arcsin(x(t)).

Comment: With `arcsine` logic alone there will be two possible choices for the angle for each input. OP wants `0-360`, `arcsine` can give only `-90-90` or `0-180`.

Comment: Yes, you need to determine what quadrant you’re in. That’s not too difficult, given that we know the crank is always turning one direction.

Comment: I would think timestamping the samples would be helpful, to correlate them better with their other data sets (magnetic stim? Freaking magnets, how do they work?)